# Mixing razor code with HTML

Tags: html, razor, syntax, markup

Hi my mark up has snippets like below

```
<thead>
    <tr class="">
        <th data-field="firstname">First Name</th>

        @{

            foreach (MapDetail geMapDetailHead in Model.mapDetails)
            {
                string firstText, secText, thirdText;

                if (geMapDetailHead.ResultTypeIDs.Equals("-9999"))
                {

                 foreach (string rt in geMapDetailHead.ResultTypeIDs.Split(','))
                    {
                 firstText = @geMapDetailHead.Name;

                 string tab = geMapDetailHead.year;

                 int? month = geMapDetailHead.Month != 0 ? geMapDetailHead.Month : (geMapDetailHead.mapheader.Month != 0 ? geMapDetailHead.mapheader.Month : 0);

                  //switch (month.GetValueOrDefault()) 
                    //{
                    //    default:
                    //        tab += "";
                    //        break;
                    //    case 1:
                    //        tab += " Jan";
                    //        break;
                    //    case 2:
                    //        tab += " Feb";
                    //        break;
                    //    case 3:
                    //        tab += " Mar";
                    //        break;
                    //    case 4:
                    //        tab += " Apr";
                    //        break;
                    //    case 5:
                    //        tab += " May";
                    //        break;
                    //    case 6:
                    //        tab += " Jun";
                    //        break;
                    //    case 7:
                    //        tab += " Jul";
                    //        break;
                    //    case 8:
                    //        tab += " Aug";
                    //        break;
                    //    case 9:
                    //        tab += " Sep";
                    //        break;
                    //    case 10:
                    //        tab += " Oct";
                    //        break;
                    //    case 11:
                    //        tab += " Nov";
                    //        break;
                    //    case 12:
                    //        tab += " Dec";
                    //        break;
                    //}

                    //secText = tab;

                   <th id=@geMapDetailHead.MapDetailID>@firstText @secText</th>

                }  @*end for loop*@
             } 
          }  @*end for loop*@
         }
      </tr>

</thead>
```

As soon as i un comment the switch statement it stops recognizing  tag as markup. i have also tried putting

```
       @:<th id=@geMapDetailHead.MapDetailID>@firstText @secText</th>
```

but did not work. How can i mix both the code and markup?

Answer (score 0):

Well turned out that i had applied 1 extra @ in the following line

```
firstText = @geMapDetailHead.Name;
```

I changed it to

```
firstText = geMapDetailHead.Name;
```

and BINGO!!
Cheers